# In angular, Spotify get token API, using the PCKE flow, returns error 404 Collection 'token' not found

Tags: angular, spotify, pkce

This problem has been bugging me a lot. I'm trying to implement the PKCE auth method described [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-pkce-flow). I have a log in button in the app template file and it is connected to the login function via `(click)`. This function creates a code_verifier saves it in the local storage and redirects the user to the Spotify authorization server login page. After Spotify redirects the user back and appends a code in the query params, I retrieve it in `ngOnInit` and subscribe to `generateToken` service. the `generateToken` then calls an API that should get the token. the problem is this API gives me ERROR 404 not found. Can you help me with this problem?

`auth.service.ts` Class functions

```
tokenUrl = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';

private generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier: string): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const data = encoder.encode(codeVerifier);
  
    return defer(()=> from(window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data)));
}

private redirectToAuthCodeFlow() {
    let codeVerifier = generateRandomString(128);
    
    localStorage.setItem('code_verifier', codeVerifier);

    return this.generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier)
}

generateCode(): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
    return this.redirectToAuthCodeFlow();
}

generateToken(code: string) {
    let codeVerifier = localStorage.getItem('code_verifier') as string;
    console.log(codeVerifier);
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-        urlencoded') };
    
    let body = new URLSearchParams({
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: environment.frontUrl,
      client_id: environment.clientId,
      code_verifier: codeVerifier
    });

    return this.http.post(this.tokenUrl, body ,options);
}
```

`app.component.ts`

```
ngOnInit(): void{
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params=>{
        const code = params['code']
        this.code = (code)? code: '';
        if (this.code){
        console.log(this.code)
        this.authServces.generateToken(this.code).subscribe(resp=>            
    {console.log(resp)})
        }
    })
}
    
login(): void{
    this.authServces.generateCode().subscribe(digest => {
        function base64encode(str: ArrayBuffer) {
        return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(str)))
          .replace(/\+/g, '-')
          .replace(/\//g, '_')
          .replace(/=+$/, '');
        }
        const codeChallenge = base64encode(digest);
        let scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';
        
        let args = new URLSearchParams({
        response_type: 'code',
        client_id: environment.clientId,
        scope: scope,
        redirect_uri: environment.frontUrl,
        code_challenge_method: 'S256',
        code_challenge: codeChallenge
        });
    
        document.location = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' + args;
    });
}
```

I tried to use postman to test what I'm doing. I entered the exact same data and it returned ERROR 400 Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.